# disable android systemui button and other components are not showing

Tags: android, webview

I am trying different options to disable system bar permanently for my android app. Now, the most successfully solution is stop the android systemui service.

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

But, this cause serious issues in my app. I have 3 android UI components on screen, 2 webviews and one videoView. Upon disabling the UI service, my webviews will show on screen for a second and then turn completely black(maybe disappeared). Only videoview is playing. Because I am refreshing the webview every 10seconds, the webview will shown up another second upon each refresh and gone. In addition, all my buttons are gone as well. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How could you consider to stop system services?

You shouldn't mess with your users' devices!

Why didn't you just try to hide the [Status bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) and/or the [Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Edit:
Another solution is to implement the Kiosk mode as in [this tutorial](http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-1/) or [Screen pinning](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise) if devices are running Lollipop

Comment: it is not a customer device. it is our own device, and we use it for demo purpose. don't want user to quit the app.

Comment: So what you want is the Kiosk Mode